# Display Child Window as part of Parent Window in Cocoa/Xamarin.Mac

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, model-view-controller, xamarin, modal-dialog

I am new to Cocoa/Xamarin and trying to implement a Login Popup window from My main Window. I have done it previously as a modal dialog, but I want to display it like the window shown in the image below.Can someone give me pointers for how to display these modal dialogs as part of the parent window?

[image]

Comment: I don't know Xamarin, but those attached dialogs are known as ["sheets"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) in Cocoa. That might help in your searching.

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases. That was what I was searching for.